# is there a way to detect native date picker calendar popup has close?

Tags: html, input, datepicker, uidatepicker, angular10

```
 <input type="date" (blur)="onDataChange()" (keyup)="onDataChange()"
                    min={{minDate}} max={{maxDate}} (focus)="selectGroupFilter('on')" 
                    formControlName="onDate" #onDate>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

For native browser date picker, when click on the icon at the right , that will open the calendar popup.
Do you know if there is a way to detect the calendar popup just close and user has selected a value from that?

Currently native date picker has issue: when user click on the arrow icon on the calendar, it will autofill the input box, and input has formcontrol which has changeDetector that will watch for changes and then trigger the api call.

If there is a  way to detect whether calendar popup has close, then I could remove the changeDetector and invoke the api call ONCE only after calendar popup is close. This will make it less costly.

However I could not figure out how to detect the calendar just close. If I could get a different classname when datepicker is open vs close, then I could detect it. However from developer console, the classname looks the same.